# Display data in specific column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Please Help Me...How can the data display to the specific column??? I don't want the data display as Toast, but I want data display as row...How can I do to achieve this? I really have no idea. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**WorkDetailsTable.Java**

```
 Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this);
                builder.setTitle("Data Saved");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                            long ab = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(WorkDetailsTable.this,DisplayData.class);

                                intent.putExtra("name",name); // pass name to DisplayData
                                startActivity(intent);
 });
```

**DisplayData.java**

```
public class DisplayData extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displaydata);
        MyDatabaseHelper db=new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        InfoAPI I1=new InfoAPI(this);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        final String name1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (name1.equals("X Y Z")) ;

        {
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            List<Info> info=I1.getAllContacts(name1); //refer to InfoAPI
            for(Info in:info)
            {
                String 

log="Weather:"+in.getWeather()+",Date:"+in.getDate()+"Status:"+in.getStatus();
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), log, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// what should write so data can be displayed in certain manner?
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

**InfoAPI.java**

```
 public List<Info> getAllContacts(String name) {

        List<Info> contactList = new ArrayList<Info>();
        String selectQuery = ("SELECT Weather,Date,Status FROM "+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO);
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO,new String[]{MyDatabaseHelper.ID,MyDatabaseHelper.Name,MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,MyDatabaseHelper.Date,MyDatabaseHelper.Status},MyDatabaseHelper.Name+"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(name)}, null, null, null, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Info contact = new Info();  //refer Info
                contact.setWeather((cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setStatus(cursor.getString(2));
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

**Info.java**

```
public class Info {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String weather;
    private String date;
   private String status;


    public Info() {
    }

    public void setStatus(String  status)
    {
        this.status=status;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setID(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setWeather(String weather)
    {
        this.weather=weather;
    }

    public String getWeather()
    {
        return this.weather;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date=date;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return this.date;
    }


}
```

[image]

**Data should be displayed in the second row**

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking. A specific column in the DB? A specific column in your layout?

Comment: specific column in my layout

Comment: Than add a textview in ur layout there and set text of that textview of the data you want to dispaly.

Comment: @But the number of row will increase everytime when the button in WorkDetailsTable is clicked. Is impossible for me to create textview in my layout right since the number of row everytime difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you're wanting to display data from a list of Info objects that are stored in a the array list contactList.

This is often best done using a ListView with a custom layout and a class that extends ArrayAdapter.  Here's a simple ArrayAdapter example that displays stock quote information:

```
  class StockArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    Context myContext;
    ArrayList<Stock> stocks;
    int myLayout;
    LayoutInflater inflator;

    public StockArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        ArrayList<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
        initialize(context, resource, stocks);
    }

    public StockArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Stock> stocks) {
        super(context, resource, stocks);

        initialize(context, resource, stocks);

    }

    private void initialize(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Stock> objects) {
        myContext = context;
        myLayout = resource;
        stocks = objects;
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = inflator.inflate(myLayout, parent, false);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView lastTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lastTextView);
        TextView changeTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.changeTextView);
        nameTextView.setText(stocks.get(position).CompanyName);
        lastTextView.setText(stocks.get(position).LastTrade);
        changeTextView.setText((stocks.get(position).Change));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This code uses a layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/lastString"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/zerosString"
        android:id="@+id/lastTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/changeString"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lastTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lastTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/zerosString"
        android:id="@+id/changeTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then typically in OnCreate you would create an instance of your adapter and assign it to a ListView using it's setAdapter method.  In my case I had a couple of fields
   ArrayList myStock;
    StockArrayAdapter myAdapter;

And had this code in my OnCreate.

```
        myStock = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    myAdapter = new StockArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.stock_row_layout, myStock);
    ListView stockListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stocksListView);
    stockListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Of course you will need to create one that displays your Info object instead, but this should give you an idea how to do it.

Comment: How to display the data in row ? and where are the fetching  data code?

Comment: Data is displayed in a row or multiple lines or any way you define based on the you chose.  In my case the layout is 2 lines for each item in the arraylist.  The "fetching" is done in the getView method.  The ArrayAdapter object calls getView once for each item in your ArrayList, passing the array index of the object to getView.  In getView YOU typically inflate a copy of your layout, assign values to the TextViews in the layout and return the inflated layout to the caller.  This inflated view is then added to a scrollablble ListView. Note this is a simple layout.

Comment: For something more impressive, you could add additional items to your layout and more complexity to your getView.  For example, I usually ask students to add an imageView and display a green up arrow if the stock price has increased as a next step for this project, a red down arrow if it's decreased or something neutral if the price is unchanged.  Or you could change the color of the background of the textview to indicate something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot stress enough: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html**

I think what you're looking for is TableLayout.

Your layout.xml should be something like

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TableLayout ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

You get a reference to it in your activity `findViewById(R.id.table)`

From there, loop through your data.

```
for (Info contact : contactList) {
    TableRow mRow = new TableRow();
    LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(...); // honestly you can just appendt he text view, but it's nice to have more control, sometimes
    TextView cellText = new TextView(...);
    cellText.setText(contact.x);
    cell.addView(cellText);
    mRow.addView(cell);
}
```

in your case, you'd add three cells per row: date, weather, status.

edit: don't forget to append rows to your table. `table.addView(mRow)`

Comment: Is it displaydata.xml?

Comment: where to get the contact.x?

Comment: `x` is a placeholder, in your case, it would be `getStatus()`, `getWeather()`, and `getDate()`

edit: don't copy my code verbatim, by the way, it's far from complete.

Comment: put the code u gave me inside DisplayData.java? Btw, I already put String 

log="Weather:"+in.getWeather()+",Date:"+in.getDate()+"Status:"+in.getStatus(); in DisplayData.

Comment: yeah... that's just making a string. Yes, put it in DataDisplay.java, basically replacing the `for-in` loop you have there, now.

Comment: new LinearLayout(...); ? What should write inside the bracket?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91881/discussion-between-tyler-sebastian-and-hoo).